Email Distribution List in Outlook for External Users
Is there a way to create a distribution list in Outlook 365 for a group of external users e.g. my clients?
The important requirement is that they should not be able to see each other's email addresses, nor should they be able to email each other by clicking reply or reply all. So, it's kind of an old-fashioned distribution list but only I can send emails to members and if anyone replies to the email, it should come back to me.
I checked the "Contact Group" in Outlook but that displays each member's name/email so that wouldn't work.

External users are my clients or my suppliers. I'm the one who needs a distribution list so that I can create one message and send it to all clients or suppliers.

To create a group wherein each member is hidden from all others, except from you, the sender, set the recipients as all BCC (blind carbon copy, from carbon paper, if you're interested in the etymology.
To add a single To recipient, such as yourself, create another group, containing the BCC group and just your email address.
Caveat: To prevent recipients seeing the header information for other recipients, each BCC email message is created and sent separately.
This is not a problem if there are not many recipients, and if the message is small. However, if there are large messages, e.g., those with images, or if there are many recipients, using BCC can slow the mail server to a crawl! This I learned through experience -- the IT department issued an edict that efficiency outranked privacy, and stated messages to a user group must be sent CC, showing all recipients.
Another BCC side effect is that messages leave the mail server serially, not simultaneously, so there might be a lag, perhaps seconds, perhaps hours, between the first recipient getting the message and the last.

Thank you for the detailed response. I really appreciate it!
